# ReactiveUI CancelableCommand with RestApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, reactiveui

I'm woring on MVVM application and trying to have a textbox text change register to run a command that can be canceled every time new change on this textbox happens.
In Reactive Extension it is done with a Switch method something like this:

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventArgs>(this, nameof(PropertyChanged))
            .Where(a => a.EventArgs.PropertyName == nameof(Item))
            .Select(a => Item)
            .DistinctUntilChanged()
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5))
            .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
            .Do(x => { Items= null; })
            .ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default)
            .Select(item => { return Observable.FromAsync(cancellationToken => _itemService.GetItemsAsyncWithCancelation(item, cancellationToken)); })
            .Switch()
            .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
            .Subscribe(items => Items = items);
```

When i try to do same thing with ReactiveUi this is what i have come up so far:

```
public ReactiveCommand GetItemsCommand { get; set; }
GetTowaryCommand = ReactiveCommand
       .CreateFromTask<string>(async (x,cancelationToken) => Items = await _itemService.GetItemsAsyncWithCancelation(x.ToString(),cancelationToken));

this.WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.Item)
       .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5))
       .Do(_=> GetTowaryCommand.Dispose())
       .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
       .InvokeCommand(GetItemsCommand);
```

It is working but i'm not sure if the RestApi call is being canceled properly.
I was trying to follow example from ReactiveUI Documentation:
https://docs.reactiveui.net/en/user-guide/commands/canceling.html
but don't know how to pass string parameter (x) to restApi method:

```
GetItemsCommand
   .CreateFromObservable<string>(() => Observable.StartAsync(async (token) => Items = await _itemService.GetItemsAsyncWithCancelation(x.ToString(), token)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't exactly know what the concrete question here is, I'll just try and see what I can do here.

Change your `GetItemsCommand` to be of type `ReactiveCommand<string, Unit>` (`string` goes in, `Unit` goes out). Then you can say:

```
GetItemsCommand.CreateFromObservable<string,Unit>(x =>
    Observable.StartAsync(async (token) => 
        Items = await _itemService.GetItemsAsyncWithCancelation(x.ToString(), token)))
```

`InvokeCommand` will automatically pass in the parameter to the command if there's one available (i.e. `Observable.Return("hello").InvokeCommand(GetItemsCommand)` will pass "hello" to the command), so you would probably need to modify whatever code invokes `GetItemsCommand`.

As a side note, you can rewrite this in a slightly more clean separation-of-concerns kinda way by returning your list from the command and setting the `Items` property in the command's `Subscribe` block:

```
public ReactiveCommand<string, IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsCommand { get; set; }

GetItemsCommand.CreateFromObservable<string, IEnumerable<T>>(x =>
    Observable.FromAsync(token =>
        _itemService.GetItemsAsyncWithCancelation(x.ToString(), token)));

// always runs on UI thread
GetItemsCommand.Subscribe(x => Items = x);
```

Also, you generally shouldn't call `ReactiveCommand.Dispose` manually (the docs you linked call `Dispose` on the *subscription*, not on the *command*). Passing in a `CancellationToken` or setting up another observable to cancel the running command (both are in your link) is generally the cleanest way to achieve that.

For example:

```
var stream = this.WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.Item)
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5))
    .DistinctUntilChanged();

stream
    .InvokeCommand(GetItemsCommand);

GetItemsCommand.CreateFromObservable<string, IEnumerable<T>>(x =>
    Observable
        .FromAsync(token => _itemService.GetItemsAsyncWithCancelation(x.ToString(), token))
        .TakeUntil(stream));

GetItemsCommand.Subscribe(x => Items = x);
```

Haven't actually tested this last bit, but I feel like it should work :) Just some ideas.

Comment: I think i get it now. Thanks a lot.